# what should i learn and look for if i like to build traffic shaper and analizer

Tags: network-programming, driver, packet-capture

i like to add and build something like WIPFW but with  traffic shaper option 
what should i learn in windows driver programing ? 
is there any code wrappers that can make it easier to program drivers stuff?

Answer (score 1):

There is [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) library which provides APIs in the user space to get and send packets in the raw form. You can use that so that you don't have to worry about device driver programming.

Comment: i know it and i like to avoid it

Comment: Any particular reason to avoid it? It is good framework and leaves out all the hasseles of writing our own hook for capturing packets.